Selenium com Python, get_attribute está retornando vazio
Eu preciso recuperar o valor do atributo 'Admin-cota-msg' do elemento 'button', descrito abaixo:
<div class="col-auto px-1 mb-2 hide-default text-center">
    <span class="font-weight-600 w-100 text-center">100</span>
        <button admin-cota-msg="Pedido #001.<br>Número premiado: 00001..." admin-cota-nr="00001" style="width: fit-content !important; display: block; padding: 3px !important; background-color: #145422; border-color: black; cursor:pointer !importan;" class="btn btn-success w-100 btn-sm py-0 px-2 text-nowrap admin-info-premiadas">
        <span class="font-weight-500">
            <span class="font-weight-600"> 00001</span>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>

Do mesmo elemento, eu consigo recuperar o valor do atributo "admin-cota-nr", utilizando o seguinte trecho:
cotas_nr = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//button[@admin-cota-nr]')
    
for i in cotas_nr:
    print(i.get_attribute("admin-cota-nr"))

Quando eu replico a mesma lógica para o atributo admin-cota-msg, nenhum valor é retornado.

Fiz um teste aqui e retoma o valor sim: 00001
Pedido #001.Número premiado: 00001...

Uma possível solução até mais simples para captar as informações de uma pagina em html é usando a biblioteca beautifulsoup.
Nesse caso usando apenas o atributo page_source da instância do webdriver, você usaria o seguinte código:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = """<div class="col-auto px-1 mb-2 hide-default text-center">
    <span class="font-weight-600 w-100 text-center">100</span>
        <button admin-cota-msg="Pedido #001.<br>Número premiado: 00001..." admin-cota-nr="00001" style="width: fit-content !important; display: block; padding: 3px !important; background-color: #145422; border-color: black; cursor:pointer !importan;" class="btn btn-success w-100 btn-sm py-0 px-2 text-nowrap admin-info-premiadas">
        <span class="font-weight-500">
            <span class="font-weight-600"> 00001</span>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>"""

txt = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html")
msg = []
nr = []

for button in txt.find_all("button"):
    msg.append(button.get("admin-cota-msg"))
    nr.append(button.get("admin-cota-nr"))

